# With org-babel, how can I reference a JSON code block with noweb?

Tags: org-babel, json

Using noweb, I'm trying to reference a JSON block

```
#+name: gazonk
#+begin_src json
{
  xyzzy "
}
#+end_src
```

```
#+begin_src shell :results verbatim :noweb yes
gazonk="${<<gazonk>>@Q}"
echo "$gazonk"
#+end_src
```

The error I'm getting is

```
unexpected EOF searching for «"»
```

I also see this with elisp

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes
(setq example-data "<<gazonk>>")
#+END_SRC
```

So, I guess the question is how to get the noweb contents into a shell variable, regardless of its contents

I've tried escaping the "<<", but I guess I'm not escaping it correctly;)

Comment: See [Noweb Reference Syntax](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Noweb-Reference-Syntax)